# ¿Utilizar un pipe dentro del archivo ts en ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic2

Realice un pipe que funciona perfectamente dentro del archivo `html`, pero estoy en un caso que necesito utilizar ese pipe dentro de mi archivo `ts`, ya importe el pipe, pero no se como se utiliza

Comment: Daniel, algo así es lo que buscas? http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview. Saludos

Comment: no, pero ya encontré la solución en stackoverflow en ingles, era muy sencillo. sin embargo dejo la Solución aquí --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653630/how-to-use-pipe-in-ts-not-html